# How to correctly populate list items for my requirement

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I was thinking of something and I would like to know if there is any solution.

I want to make a program, where when I am going to press the "add" `button`, a new row will be created with an `Edittext` on left and a `TextView` on right. Every time I press the "add" `button`, a new row with an `Edittext` and a `Textview` will be added.

I have read some tutorials, but all said for only one field and the use of a `listview`.

How can I add both fields?  
I can't figure out how can I set the position of each row and field? For example, I want the 2 fields to have 30dp distance or each row has distance 25dp.  
Also, how will I know the id of each one in order to make some calculations?

Can anyone explain me something, give some code or suggest me any tutorial?

Thank you very much!

Something like below (I made it on paint)

[image]

**...UPDATE...**

So, I make some changes to go a little bit further.. I made two lists for TextViews and EditTexts in order to retrieve them later easier.. But It get stuck when I press the button for the second time.. In the first press, it creates the first row, but in the second press, it stuck and not even craches. I am sure, is something stupid that I haven't see it..

```
        EditText ed;
        List<EditText> allEds = new ArrayList<EditText>();
        TextView tv;
        List<TextView> allTvs = new ArrayList<TextView>();

        for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

            ed = new EditText(Main_5.this);
            allEds.add(ed);
            ed.setId(counter);
            ed.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
            linearLayout.addView(ed);
            ed.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER| InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);


            tv = new TextView(Main_5.this);
            allTvs.add(tv);
            tv.setId(counter);
            tv.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
            linearLayout.addView(tv);

            mainLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);

        }
```

Also, could you give me a little help for retreiving the ids?? I am trying to get the EditText id's and show then on specific TextView id's.. I thought something like this for start, but I cannot test it because of the error.. And I want to take it further in order to put on TextView the EditText.. Any ideas??

```
Double[] doubles = new Double[allEds.size()];

        for(i=0;i<allEds.size();i++){

            doubles[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toDouble();

        }
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Not much..  
I just made the xml and then I tried with a listview, but I couldn't put both fields, only the textview...  
Just to see and store whatever I wrote..

Comment: post any code you have tried and i'll help you out.

Comment: easy. You can do it using a list view. 
you have your main view and a list view inside that. For each list item (each raw) you need to have a view. so you need to create that as well.that's where you add your edit text and text view.Then you need to inflate that list item view to your list view. Then you need to pass data to your list view. eg.How many items you want.. you can increment number of items when user clicks on that creation button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i've just written a quick program to help you with your problem. This will need tweaking to suit your case.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Row"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So here we add a Button to add the things you would like and a LinearLayout to contain them.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mainLinearLayout;
    private int counter = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mainLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
                linearLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                editText.setId(counter);
                editText.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
                editText.setHint("Edit Text");
                TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textView.setId(counter);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.5f));
                textView.setText("TextView");
                linearLayout.addView(editText);
                linearLayout.addView(textView);
                mainLinearLayout.addView(linearLayout);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So what this will do now is when the add row button is clicked, it'll create a new instance of an `EditText` and a new instance of a `TextView` and add them to a horizontal `LinearLayout` and then add that linearlayout to the parent linearLayout created in the XML.

Comment: Thank you very much!! It work perfectly...
But how could I know the id of each field in order to make some calculations??

Comment: you could use a counter, so every time the button is click it'll add one to the counter and assign the EdiText and TextView an id such as "et" + counter and "tv" + counter, so then you'll know based on the number of rows you have what id belongs to which row.

Comment: ive edited the code to show you what you would need to do.

Comment: I have no words!!!
Just one tiny problem.. I get an error for the setId "non-static method 'setId(int)' cannot be referenced from a static context".   
I searched it, but I didn't found solution for the specific occation..

Comment: try setId(counter) instead, i think it doesn't accept a string but it does an int.

Comment: Yes, it fixed it!!   
But the main problem was that at first it was EditText.setId(counter);  
but it want editText.setId(counter);  
I didn't see it!!
I will try now to make my calculations!!

Thank you aaaaalll very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

oh!
I added and a clear button for everyone who search it.

```
    Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          mainLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
        }
    });
```